# I don't have ANY packages

Tags: 14.04, package-management

I'm very very new to Ubuntu and used it for the first time 3 days ago for a project my teacher put me on. He told me to get chrome working on the Lenovo ThinkPads R500's. Turns out, after some searching I've discovered that I have no packages installed. I have no idea where to start with any of these. 
I typed "dpkg --get-selections", and every single line has "Install" beside it, I'm assuming that means something lol. Every time I attempt to install anything it tells me I have held broken packages.

I'm not sure what else to say, thanks a lot in advance.

**This is the output I get when I try to install software center:**

```
root@teapot-ThinkPad-R500:~# apt-get install software-center*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'ubuntu-kylin-software-center-common' for regex 'software-center*'
Note, selecting 'software-center-aptdaemon-plugins' for regex 'software-center*'
Note, selecting 'lubuntu-software-center' for regex 'software-center*'
Note, selecting 'software-center' for regex 'software-center*'
Note, selecting 'ubuntu-kylin-software-center' for regex 'software-center*'
software-center is already the newest version.
software-center-aptdaemon-plugins is already the newest version.
software-center-aptdaemon-plugins set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-kylin-software-center : Depends: language-pack-zh-hans but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post there output of a command, when you try to install something. Did you try to run `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Is it Kylin installed?

Comment: You are not on Ubuntu, are you?

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

Ubuntu uses 'apt' as a package management tool. To install any package, this is the syntax:

```
sudo apt-get install <package-name>
```

So all you need is the package name. To search among the PPAs on your system, you can use this:

```
apt-cache search <keyword>
```

So with this command you can search for packages. So when you search for chrome by executing the following command, you won't see Google Chrome listed:

```
sudo apt-cache search chrome
```

This means it is not in the PPAs added to your system. So I add the required PPA:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add - 
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
sudo apt-get update
```

After executing the above three commands and searching forr chrome again, you will see entries for Chrome. Naturally you'd want to install the stable version:

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

**Method 2**

Or you could take the GUI approach, by downloading the .deb file and opening it. Then `Ubuntu Software Center` will open and all you'll need to do is click `Install`.

Answer (score 0):

```
press CTRL+T
```

This will open terminal.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Enter your account password.

```
apt-get upgrade
```

This will install updates.

```
apt-get install <the package you need to install>
```

**this will install your package**

Comment: Output from sudo apt-get updates:

W: GPG error: http://security.kali.org kali/updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY ED444FF07D8D0BF6
W: GPG error: http://http.kali.org kali InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY ED444FF07D8D0BF6
root@teapot-ThinkPad-R500:~#

Comment: sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver security.kali.org ED444FF07D8D0BF6